# translate more than one imageview in different ways

Tags: android

I've been playing around with animations - just to get my head round how they work really.  I've got most things I want to do working, but one thing I've got stuck on is how to translate different image views in different ways. (I've left the rotates all the same, which is fine for now). In the code I've put in below, I have 5 images, and I thought that if I made the parameters in each translateAnimation different, then each image view would do a different thing, but they don't, they all do the same thing.  I don't quite get what all the parameters do yet, so I was hoping to be able to see the differences by having different sets of parameters for different images, and comparing what happened to each one on the screen.  I put them all in a set animation, so I don't know if this is the problem?  Or the fact that they're in an array?  Or have I not made the parameters different enough, so to the naked eye it all looks the same?  Or is there a silly bug in my code that I've missed? Or is it just not possible to do what I want?  If I take them out of the setAnimation, it only seems to move the first one, and ignores the rest.  I'd particularly like to get one to go up the screen, one to go down, one to go across L to R, one to go across R to L, and one to go diagonally, all at the same time, but starting to wonder if this just isn't possible?

public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

```
    final ImageView[] w = new ImageView[5];

    w[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.w1);
    w[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.w2);
    w[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.w3);
    w[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.w4);
    w[4] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.w5);

    //animate images.
    //First set up an AnimationSet to put all the animations into
    AnimationSet move_w = new AnimationSet(true);
    //set up the rotations for each image
    RotateAnimation rotate_w[] = new RotateAnimation[5];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        rotate_w[i] = new RotateAnimation(0f, 300f, w[i].getWidth()/2, w[i].getHeight()/2);
        rotate_w[i].setStartOffset(50);
        rotate_w[i].setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        rotate_w[i].setDuration(9500);
        move_w.addAnimation(rotate_w[i]);
    }

    //set up the translations (across the screen movements)
    TranslateAnimation trans_w[] =  new TranslateAnimation[5];
    trans_w[0] =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, -10, Animation.ABSOLUTE, -10, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, (float) 0.8);
    trans_w[1] =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.3f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.9f);
    trans_w[2] =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -0.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.3f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.9f);
    trans_w[3] =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.1f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.3f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, -0.9f);
    trans_w[4] =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.3f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.9f);

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {

        trans_w[i].setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        trans_w[i].setDuration(12000);
        move_w.addAnimation(trans_w[i]);

    }
        move_w.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);

    if(hasFocus) {

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            w[i].startAnimation(move_w);
        }
    } else {

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
           w[i].setAnimation(null);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, use me code instead of your. At the point u've done this good, but u miss'd up one think. U has 5 `ImageView's` and one `AnimationSet` and this is incorrect, cause for one `View` u pass 2 animation. So u must to have 5 `AnimationSet's`.

And code:

```
 w[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.w1);
        w[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.w2);
        w[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.w3);
        w[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.w4);
        w[4] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.w5);

        //animate images.
        //First set up an AnimationSet to put all the animations into
        AnimationSet[] move_w = new AnimationSet[5];
        //set up the rotations for each image
        RotateAnimation rotate_w[] = new RotateAnimation[5];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            rotate_w[i] = new RotateAnimation(0f, 300f, w[i].getWidth()/2, w[i].getHeight()/2);
            rotate_w[i].setStartOffset(50);
            rotate_w[i].setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            rotate_w[i].setDuration(9500);
            move_w[i] = new AnimationSet(true);
            move_w[i].addAnimation(rotate_w[i]);
        }

        //set up the translations (across the screen movements)
        TranslateAnimation trans_w[] =  new TranslateAnimation[5];
        trans_w[0] =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, -10, Animation.ABSOLUTE, -10, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, (float) 0.8);
        trans_w[1] =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.3f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.9f);
        trans_w[2] =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -0.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.3f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.9f);
        trans_w[3] =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.1f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.3f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, -0.9f);
        trans_w[4] =  new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.3f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.9f);

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            trans_w[i].setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            trans_w[i].setDuration(2000);
            move_w[i].addAnimation(trans_w[i]);
            move_w[i].setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
        }

        if(hasFocus) {
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                w[i].startAnimation(move_w[i]);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                w[i].setAnimation(null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I shall try this.  Not had chance yet.

Comment: This does seem to work, thank you.  I'm going to have more of a play around with it later

Comment: Heh. This is funny  ^)